# Access: DAO reference guid changed, resulting in an .mde not starting up in Access 14 (2010) on Win7

Tags: ms-access, windows-7, vba, dao

2 Feb 2011: I started this thread under the impression that my M$ technet thread about it was dead. But there is a new post about the subject, please have a look at it: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpro/thread/56e098b9-210b-4afe-8531-c526fb3e4464[1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpro/thread/56e098b9-210b-4afe-8531-c526fb3e4464). Not a solution, but a confirmation that the combination of 7, 14 and mde is crucial.

--Original Post:

Since we still have clients using Office 9 (2000), we deploy our frontend in an .mde file format (database format of Access 2000) for all Access versions 9 to 14 (2010) rather than "compiling" an .mde for older and an .accde for newer Access versions. Due to their economic situation, we often find a mixture of all Office and Windows versions on our clients' workstations in one company, so the least possibility is our answer. This was no problem with an .mde until Office 14 in combination with Windows 7. I analyzed everything enough to be sure now that there is a reproducible issue with an .mde starting up in Access 14 in combination with Windows 7 -- Access 14 on XP will work.

We have some references in our VBA project, among them Word and DAO. The Word ref. works on every Access version 9 to 14 without a problem, it will automatically find the appropriate version since the guid is the same from Office 9 to 14. Between Office 12 (2007) and 14 (2010) M$ changed not only the dll file name for DAO but, what's crucial in my understanding, the reference GUID. Have Access detect the new DAO version will fail under Access 14 under Windows 7, but only with an .mde, an .mdb, an .accdb and an .accde will start up without a problem, and an .mde will start up in Access 14 under XP, as mentioned. So this is a combination of the changed GUID and a system right to ... do what? Find a file, scan the registry for the information necessary here?

I assume there will not be a one or two step "trick" for this, but I would be grateful for hints what to check in Windows 7, or even, how to change our VBA code to get rid of this problem. Regarding the last option: We have many, many explicit Dim ... As DAO.... throughout our code.

Comment: I wonder if you can do something with conditional compilation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx ) and add from file (Set ref = References.AddFromFile(strFileName) ?

Comment: What version of DAO are you currently referencing?   3.6?   Also, not that it matters because it's working, I find it quite surprising that the same reference to Word works with different Word versions.

Comment: @Remou: I was told that you cannot set or edit a reference from an .mde, neither by VBA code nor via menu command. It seems though as if Access 2010 successfully adopts a DAO 3.6 ref. to an acedao.dll, change the GUID, but let the reference name alone ("DAO"), in an mdb, accd?, and under XP even in an mde. I will nevertheless test if a .AddFromFile works in an mde.

Comment: @Tony, comment: Yes, DAO 3.6. And as I answered to Remou, this is successfully adopted by Access without any programmer's intervention (and no possibility for the programmer to intervene) to a new file and Ref GUID at runtime, more precise, on first startup on the Access 14 machine, but not in an mde under Windodws 7. The Word ref is adopted with every Access (Runtime) version inc. 14 (2010) under every Windows version without a problem, but only upwards, so I deploy an mde with a Word 9 reference "compiled" on an Access 9 (2000) machine.

Comment: @Tony, answer: The code will not give any information because the DAO ref IsBroken property is False. Querying the .FullPath of the DAO ref. will result in an error message in both an mdb and an mde though, in Access 14, regardless if dao360.dll exists and is registered. Access apparently redirects DAO calls to acedao.dll intransparently, if it does, and I did not find a way to trigger, allow nor control this adoption procedure. Access shows a message box that it searches for a referenced file and adopts the ref., in an mdb. After that "search" the GUID for the "DAO" ref has changed.

Comment: ... So IMHO I have two possibilities: To find out which policy hinders Access 14 to find acedao.dll for the "DAO" ref under Windows 7, or, the most inconvenient way for my clients / customers, deploy a legacy version of our product in Access 9 and a current version in Access 14. Technically, the third option would be to define new requirements for our product (Access 11? -> .accde?), but not practically. Hope I won't be alleged to crosspost, tech details in my dead M$ technet thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitpro/thread/56e098b9-210b-4afe-8531-c526fb3e4464.

Answer (score 0):

As code won't format properly in the comments windows I have to use an answer.  Please run the following code and report back the results.

```
Sub ViewMoreReferenceDetails()

Dim refIDE As Object

    For Each refIDE In Access.Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References
        If refIDE.IsBroken = True Then
            Debug.Print "Broken, GUID - " & refIDE.Guid
        Else
            Debug.Print refIDE.Description & " - " & refIDE.Name & " - " & _
                refIDE.Major & "." & refIDE.Minor & vbCrLf & _
                "       Location - " & refIDE.FullPath
        End If
    Next refIDE

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised a Word reference to a specific version will fix itself. I always use late binding with anything other than the default 3 Access references, Access, VBA and DAO.

DAO can be a problem in certain situations, and one of those is if you've got multiple versions of Access installed on the machine where you compile the MDE or in the production environment. An incomplete re-registration of Access can cause it to be broken, even though it's registered as the main version of Access. A complete run of the installation (or a repair of the Office install) should fix that.

For other considerations, see [Michael Kaplan's article on the subject of references](http://www.trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet026.asp?1033). It touches on DAO registration issues, and specifically mentions the case where DAO is broken, but IsBroken returns False nonetheless. What he says there may give you some ideas on some approaches for the problem.

But in my experience, the error you're getting is a sign of a corrupted Access installation.

Comment: Thank you David, but this does not fit to the information given in the original post: The behaviour of Access 14 under Windows 7 regarding the DAO ref is reproducible, with our mde. Would be a major coincidence if installation was incomplete on my machine and some customers' machines, and if in all cases the link would have been broken only for MDEs but not for MDBs and ACCD?s.Unfortunately

Comment: In my experience, the Word reference is no problem at all, and I am sure that there is a correlation between the fact that Word ref GUID remained the same while DAO ref GUID changed, and my issue here. As to my research, DAO cannot be late binded, so I cannot even try if that would be a solution. -- I read the linked article with interest and found information about Access 95 and 97 and about general handling of broken refs, but not about refs that are not broken but just not successfully adapted to a newer version in a certain database document type while a bunch of others are fine.

Comment: DAO can certainly be late bound, though I wouldn't recommend it. The Application.CurrentDB object gives you access to the entire DAO hierarchy without any need for a DAO reference. Again, I would never do that, but the point is that it is possible.

Comment: I'm not certain you've fully appreciated the content of Michael Kaplan's article. It seems to me that you should be able to fix up a broken reference by following his advice. That is, you should be able to switch from DAO360 to the new ACE DAO DLL. But one thing that I've never quite understood is that MDBs created in A2007 still use DAO360 as the reference instead of the ACE version of DAO.